# scope equivalent in rails 2.3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to generate a  group of routes under an `admin` scope **without** having to create a new physical directory (like `namespace` requires you to).

I know that in Rails 3 there is a `scope` method on the route mapper, and this appears to do what I want, but apparently it doesn't exist in Rails 2.3.x

My goal is to have a route like this: `"/admin/products"` map to `"app/controllers/products_controller`, ***not*** `"app/controllers/admin/products_controller"`.

Is there any way to accomplish this in Rails 2.3.x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you need to use `:name_prefix` and `:path_prefix` to get to what you want:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.with_options :name_prefix => 'admin_', :path_prefix => 'admin' do |admin|
    admin.resources :products
  end
end
```

Will yield routes:

> ```
>     admin_products GET    /admin/products(.:format)          {:controller=>"products", :action=>"index"}
>                    POST   /admin/products(.:format)          {:controller=>"products", :action=>"create"}
>  new_admin_product GET    /admin/products/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"products", :action=>"new"}
> edit_admin_product GET    /admin/products/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"products", :action=>"edit"}
>      admin_product GET    /admin/products/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"products", :action=>"show"}
>                    PUT    /admin/products/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"products", :action=>"update"}
>                    DELETE /admin/products/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"products", :action=>"destroy"}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be not well documented, but `namespace` is actually a very simple wrapper for `with_options`. It sets the `:path_prefix`, `:name_prefix`, and `:namespace` options, of which I believe you only want the first, so:

```
map.with_options :path_prefix => 'admin/' do |admin|
  admin.connect ':controller/:action'
end
```

I'm going through this from reading the code. It looks like `:name_prefix` is used to give named routes a prefix, and `:namespace` is used to actually look in subdirectories.